# camera, compound, or curved mirror

Tags: word-meaning

Does "compound" here mean "a chemical that combines two or more elements"?

> Richard Dawkins tweeted today:
> There’s only a few ways to make an eye & natural selection has discovered them all. If there’s alien life, it’s safe to predict eyes built on familiar lines – **camera,  compound,  or curved mirror.** Or do we just lack the imagination to think of other possibilities? Discuss.

> Source:  [Twitter](https://twitter.com/RichardDawkins/status/1384438540898013189)

Comment: Google ["compound eyes".](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22compound+eyes%22&oq=%22compound+eyes%22&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dawkins is referring to compound eyes

> A compound eye is a visual organ found in arthropods such as insects
> and crustaceans. It may consist of thousands of ommatidia,[1] which
> are tiny independent photoreception units that consist of a cornea,
> lens, and photoreceptor cells which distinguish brightness and color.
> The image perceived by this arthropod eye is a combination of inputs
> from the numerous ommatidia, which are oriented to point in slightly
> different directions. Compared with single-aperture eyes, compound
> eyes have poor image resolution; however, they possess a very large
> view angle and the ability to detect fast movement and, in some cases,
> the polarization of light.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_eye

Comment: He is referring to three types of eye that occur in nature. (Ours work like cameras.)